# Hide components in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to hide a custom component in Angular. I have a children and parent component, the child component is inside the template of the parent:

`<comp (add) = "onAdd($event)"> </comp>`

So, when i'm trying to hide the component, it works. It works with writing hidden in the tag or setting display : none or with ngIf.

But the problem is, when i'm hiding the component the event doesn't work (->(add) = "onAdd($event)") The data which im passing from children to parent is important for services, so i need a solution to hide the component without losing the data which is passed.

The data is passed with EventEmitter from child component.

Thank you in advice.

Comment: If you rely on a component that isn't there, because it's been removed by ngIf, for something to happen, there's a design problem. How could something that doesn't exist notify its parent on anything? It doesn't exist. There can't be an "add" on a component that doesn't exist. What is this "add" event. What are you trying to achieve, at a higher level?

Comment: How something can produce a event which is not displayed or hidden or does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the key, in this case, would be to `emit` from the Child Component during the change. Something along the lines of this can be achieved in the `ngOnChanges` in the Child Component while passing some `@Input` data to the ChildComponent from your Parent Component.

I've created a **[Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-child-emit-when-parent-change-visibility?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)** to demo this.

But that's not the case in most of the scenarios. In most of the cases, you generally emit from the Child Component when the user interacts with the Child's Template. But since the user will not see the Child in the first place, it won't really be possible as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @JenkyG, were you able to achieve what you were trying to using this approach?